# Placement of text and toggle button

Tags: react-native

I want to place a text and a toggle button in such a manner that the Text should be there at `flex-start` and the toggle would be there at the flex end. I have come up with the following code :

```
<TouchableRipple onPress={() => { }}>
                                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                                        <FontAwesome5 name="bookmark" size={16} />   Booked
                                    </Text>
                                    <View pointerEvents="none" style={{justifyContent: "flex-end"}}>
                                        <Switch value={true} />
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableRipple>
```

But the view is coming as follows:

[image]

How can I put the same at the end ?

Any help would be appritiated.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this

```
<TouchableRipple onPress={() => { }}>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
         <View style={{flex:1}}> //wrap Text inside view with flex 1
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
               <FontAwesome5 name="bookmark" size={16} />   Booked
            </Text>
         </View>
        <View pointerEvents="none" style={{flex:1,justifyContent: "flex-end"}}> //add flex 1 here
           <Switch value={true} />
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableRipple>
```